# Import external files in Django

Tags: django, django-settings

i am currently working in Django . The values in the settings.py would change depending upon the scenerio . So what i thought was to have a JSON file , that would contain the setting values. So that we can import that file in Settings.py . So whenever there is a change in the settings.py values , it would be enough to change this JSON . How can i do it ?

Comment: I'd recommend using environment variables. Django-environ(https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) makes it really easy. You basically define a file called .env with your desired settings and change variables in your settings.py to use those values.

Comment: Can you tell how to use it ?